# How do I make sure that the user enters their input fields correctly?

Tags: usability, input-fields, formatting

I have two input fields which need to be formatted a certain way. Ipv4 addresses need to have the "." to separate the numbers and ipv6 addresses need to have ":". I'm not sure what the best text should be in order to ensure the user enters their data correctly. Should I show them an example of the format (like the image below)? I wanted to use something like `mm/dd/yyyy`, but there is no equivalent for IP addresses.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straightforward solution to this. Using [masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_mask) is an option, but determining the number of digits in the IP is a challenge.

**I would suggest adopting a post-interaction strategy**: start by validating if the user is including dots in IPv4 and colons in IPv6. This initial step will assist in conducting a basic check to ensure that the format is correct. **Although it doesn't confirm the validity of the address, it helps in maintaining the proper format**.

Realistically, in most instances, users are **unlikely to input information manually**. They would rather copy and paste, which implies that your main task might be to sanitize blank spaces at most. Thus, I believe any possible issues will come with user testing, right now you can't do much than what you already did and the additional steps I mention. If it works or not is something you'll find out at a later time